# floating fluid with force fields

Tags: fluid-simulation

Is there any way I can make fluid float in the air with force fields? I am trying to replicate this: [image]

Also, is there any plugin that would help?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what hasn't worked for you? It is helpful to share what your research into your problem has been when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use force fields to do this. You can use an object in the fluid domain with fluid controller settings. Once baking, the fluid domain will be attracted towards the control object (if you have set it's strength to do so). You can animate some of the settings for the controller so that the fluid moves around the object.